# Qt Connect Signal with parameter in Lambda Function

Tags: c++, qt, lambda

I am new to Qt, I am working with lambda functions. I have a serial port object Serial. That I am reading and writing and also I want to do operations when it's ready to read or when bytes are written.

This works perfectly for readyRead signal:

```
   QObject::connect(Serial, &QSerialPort::readyRead, [=]() {
    /* DO SOMETHING 1*/
    }
```

My problem is that this doesn't work, even when I know that I received for sure a signal bytesWritten. I never go inside /* DO SOMETHING 2*/ section.

```
QObject::connect(Serial, &QSerialPort::bytesWritten, [=]() {
    /* DO SOMETHING 2*/
});
```

Did I do a mistake?
I also noticed that there is a difference between the two signals bytesWritten and readyRead in syntax as shown next.

```
void QIODevice::readyRead()

void QIODevice::bytesWritten(qint64 bytes)
```

Maybe it has something to do with the fact that bytesWritten has a parameter that I didn't add (didn't know where to add).

Thank you for your help if you notice any problem!

Comment: In general, either the lambda is connected or you get a compile time error. (Concerning this, a lambda doesn't make a difference to a plain function or a pair of `QObject*` and member function.) In your 2nd case, you drop the signal call argument which is not prohibited. (Though, it's there for a reason...) If your signal handler with `/* DO SOMETHING 2*/` is never called, the reason might be that the corresponding signal is never emitted. Maybe, check for the latter...

Comment: Please, note that the doc. of [QIODevice::bytesWritten()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#bytesWritten) mentions cases where the signal is not emitted. To be sure whether this is the possible reason in your code you should [edit] your question and provide a [mcve]. (A [mcve] is a good idea anyway.)

Answer (score 1):

Your lambda needs to have the same signature as the signal it's connecting to. So yes, you need to add the parameter. To do that, simply pass it in the parentheses:

```
QObject::connect(Serial, &QSerialPort::bytesWritten, [=](qint64 bytes) {
    /* DO SOMETHING 2*/
});
```

Comment: _Your lambda needs to have the same signature as the signal it's connecting to._ That's not quite correct. Please, see my above comment. (I even just checked it in one of my own samples to be more than 100 % sure.) ;-)

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I was not being precise.